# Is it possible to use the Markup tool on an image selected from UIImagePickerController?

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, image-editing

Is there a way to markup images after taking a picture using a UIImagePickerController. I'd ideally like to use a Native solution but would also be willing to code it myself if anyone has an idea how to implement it.

I've tried setting the picker to allow editing but this seems to only allow you to crop/resize the image.

```
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I'd like to have access to this screen similar to what's available in photos/email/etc.

[image: I'd like to have access to this screen similar to what's available in photos/email/etc.]

Using the UIImagePickerController only allows simple editing.

[image: Using the UIImagePickerController only allows simple editing.]